# How to get fixed error related Parsing the DateTime object?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm getting this error related to Datetime not being recognized. Being afraid of messing up further more, it's hard for me to figure out the fix.
I appreciate someone telling me how I can fix this?

I get this error when I run the program:

> [FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.]
>      System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles) +12614002
>      System.DateTime.Parse(String s) +25

```
public ActionResult Create(QuizFormViewModel viewModel) 
{
    var quiz = new Quiz
                {
                    StudentId= User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                    DateTime = DateTime.Parse(
                                string.Format($"{viewModel.Date} {viewModel.Time}"))
                };

    _context.Guizzes.Add(quiz);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Edit:

Here is the Date and Time in the ViewModel.

```
    public string Date { get; set; }

    public string Time { get; set; }
```

and in my cshtml file I have this code:

```
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Date)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "1 Jan 2019" })
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Time)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Time, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "24:00" })
</div>
```

Comment: What are the exact string representations of `viewModel.Date` and `viewModel.Time`? The error is saying that, when put together with a space between them, it doesn't represent a valid `DateTime`. Also, do you have a property named after a type? It may be better to give it a more informative name, such as `RegistrationDate` or `StartTime`.

Comment: Try with `ParseExact` and `d MMM yyyy HH:mm` and an _english-based_ culture like `InvariantCulture`. Edit: I just figured out that `HH` can't parse `24` as an hour which usually represented as `00:00`. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock#Midnight_00:00_and_24:00

Comment: Thanks. Naming it to RegistrationDatet/Time would be much better.

Comment: It doesn't accept ParseExact. It gives error: "No overload for method 'ParseExact' takes 1 arguments.

Comment: @user10489212 Because it doesn't. See it's documentation, It needs at least 3 parameter. https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How any given number or DateTime has to be written is highly dependant on culture. By default Parse (wich is called by TryParse and Convert) will extract the current culture from the Windows User Settings. I am not sure where in that process the specification of a Format String sets in. But you are doing a WebApplicaiton, and there is usually a disconnect between the Users Culture and the Culture of your server.

The bigger issue seems to be that you split it up and turned it into strings in the first place. A time without a Date and a Timezone (even if just implied) is pretty much useless the moment your programm can cross even a single timezone border. And string is just the 2nd worst storage and transmission format. It is the kind you have to pick in some cases (User I/O, XML) but want to avoid everywhere else. ASP.Net does have existing Date and Time Picker elements. And any DBMS worth it's memory will also have a DateTime type.

Comment: Thanks for an insightful explaination. I had to seperately use them in the cshtml file. If there is any better solution anyone suggest that I would avoid this error, I kindly appreciate that.

Comment: Despite all the good thoughts, I still havn't fixed the issue. If someone could come with a concrete solution please!

Comment: @user10489212: Without knowing wich Concrete Input at wich implied culture cause the concrete exception, we can not help you.

Comment: What you are saying is that the implementation is fine, but the user input triggers this error? I want it to be international format.

Comment: @user10489212: There is no "international" Format. There is one format for each culture. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0j74jcxSunY And internationalization is not a trivial thing by any measurement.

Comment: the problem solved now. thanks to your comments. It was due to the the date and time format. If one of them was given differently, it would throw this error.